# Use of "had" in this sentence

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

This sentence pertains to a movie I watched:

1. I wish I watched it with subtitles.
2. I wish I **had** watched it with subtitles.

What effect does adding **had** have on the sentence? Are both sentences correct? Is one form preferred over the other?

Comment: in this type of sentence the main verbs are in their preterite forms not to mark past time, but because you are talking about a situation contrary to fact (this is the "modal" use of the preterite). the reason the second one is more clear is because the first is ambiguous between a case where you habitually watch the same movie without subtitles (and regret this habit of yours) and one where you watched a movie once in the past without subtitles (and regret this choice). in the second one the auxiliary have indicates that you are dealing with a single, completed action.

Answer (score 1):

The first example is often used in informal speech.

However, I did not actually watch it with subtitles. Therefore a suggestion that I *should* have calls for a subjunctive construction.

The second is the preferred grammatical construct, the pluperfect subjunctive.